# How to make sure ALL asp.net custom validators are passing, not just one

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

This is kind of a silly question, in that it is very trivial and yet confusing to find a straight answer on.

I have a series of custom validators for a form, all of which seem to be working appropriately.  I am writing in VB.net right now, for these.

When the user clicks the submit button, I do this:

```
Protected Sub Submission_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
        Page.Validate()
        If (Page.IsValid) Then
        ... //Go on to accept the form.
        End If
End Sub
```

Here is the problem: If a single one of my custom validators passes, then args.IsValid is set to true and thus in the above code, it goes straight into the If and on to submitting the form to the DB.

```
Protected Sub AffidavitValidator_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles AffidavitValidator.ServerValidate
    If (Not AffidavitYes.Checked = True And Not AffidavitNo.Checked = True) Then
        args.IsValid = False
    ElseIf (AffidavitNo.Checked = True) Then
        args.IsValid = False
    ElseIf (AffidavitYes.Checked = True) Then
        args.IsValid = True
    End If
End Sub
```

So for example, if they select Yes for this "Yes or No" on the page, then the form is automatically validated since args.IsValid = True, *even if they do not even fill out any of the other fields*.  This is a big problem, because this is not at all the intended effect of having the multiple validators.  I want the form to be accepted only if *all* of the validators pass.

I need to make sure that should any ***one*** of the custom validator functions set args.IsValid = False, then the form should not be validated and thus not be accepted.

Now here is a little more info.  I set all of my custom validators to be in the same ValidationGroup, and I also set all of them to validate on empty (that is, to still run their custom validation function even if the user never touched the control at all).

I think because the "Yes or No" bullets are at the bottom of the page, they are the last to be validated in my Submission_Click function. Thus, even though the other validators may be setting args.IsValid to false, since this last one is setting it to true, then the form is accepted.  However I don't really know how to rectify this in a succinct and effective manner.

Comment: Why don't you use: asp:RequiredFieldValidator as well to make sure the fields are filled.

Comment: This is a good thought, but I think that although this will force entry for each required field, that the form will still be accepted (because of the above problem) even with bad data in the field.

Comment: You could wrap you logic in IF Page.IsValid.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Are your checks radiobuttons whereby they toggle between yes and no?

Comment: Yes Mych, they must select one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Through tinkering with the different properties of the ASP.net validator controls, I've figured out what was going wrong.  **The "Visible" property must be set to true.**  For them to be rendered at all, including their CodeBehind.   (To me, this isn't very intuitive, since I thought that the Visible property would refer only to their display, and not their CodeBehind -- as it turns out, if visible is set to false, the control is not only not displayed but its codebehind is not run)